# Null pointer exception on view pager swipe

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am getting null pointer exception when I try to make reverse swiping or repeated swiping between fragments in viewpager I am not getting the real issue behind this.My code is as follows

```
public class Actionbar extends FragmentActivity{


private AuthDb authDb;
SampleFragmentPagerAdapter adapter;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.action_bar);
    authDb = new AuthDb(getApplicationContext());
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    adapter=new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    if(Reference.SEARCH_COLOR.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
    {
        setTitle("Search");
    }
    if(Reference.ACTIONBARTITLE){
        Reference.ACTIONBARTITLE=false;
        showIcon();
    }
   System.out.println("inside actionbarrrrr");
}


public void showIcon(){

    try{

    }
catch (NullPointerException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

catch (Exception e) {

```
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
public void setTitle(String title){

}


public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private String tabtitles[] = new String[] { "Feed", "Profile", "Search","Followers","Settings" };

    final int PAGE_COUNT = 5;

    public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter() {
        super(getSupportFragmentManager());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;              
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment frm = null;
        System.out.println("scrolling position"+position+":count: "+PAGE_COUNT);
        if(position==0){

            frm=FeedFragment.create(position);
        }
        else if(position==1){
            frm=ProfileFragment.create(position);
        }
        else if(position==2){
            frm=SearchFragment.create(position);
        }
        else if(position==3){
            frm=FollowersFragment.create(position,"me");
        }
        else if(position==4){
            frm=SettingFragment.create(position);
        }
        else{
            frm=FeedFragment.create(position);
        }
        return frm;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return tabtitles[position];
    }
}
```

}

one fo my fragment

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.hasExtra("foloCount") && (mFolloCount != null)) {
            mFolloCount.setText(intent.getStringExtra("foloCount"));
        }
        if (intent.hasExtra("msgCount") && (mMsgCount != null)) {
            String User_Message_Count = intent.getStringExtra("msgCount");
            if (User_Message_Count.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                mMsgCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                mMsgCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mMsgCount.setText(User_Message_Count);
            }
        }
        if (intent.hasExtra("notiCount") && (mMsgCount != null)) {
            String User_Notification_Count = intent
                    .getStringExtra("notiCount");
            if (User_Notification_Count.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                mNotifyCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                mNotifyCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mNotifyCount.setText(User_Notification_Count);
            }
        }

    }
};
private AlarmManager alarm;
private PendingIntent pIntent;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        if (!(activity instanceof FragmentActivity)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(((Object) this).getClass()
                    .getSimpleName()
                    + " must be attached to a FragmentActivity.");

        }
        mHomeActivity = (FragmentActivity) activity;

    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnNavigateProfileListener ");
    }
    System.out.println("step 215");
}

@Override
  public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) { 

        if(Constants.DIALOGOPEN){
            Constants.DIALOGOPEN=false;
            Constants.dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
    else {  }
  }
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("inside profile fragment");

    mViewUtils = new ViewUtils(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    dbHelper = new QsDatabaseHelper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    context = getActivity();

    mSportDb = new SportDb(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    mOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheOnDisc(true)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.noimagesmall)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.noimagesmall)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
            .considerExifParams(true).build();

    mImageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    ImageLoaderConfiguration imageLoaderConfiguration = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            getActivity()).defaultDisplayImageOptions(mOptions)
            .threadPoolSize(3).build();

    mImageLoader.init(imageLoaderConfiguration);
    System.out.println("inside profile fragment");               
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container,
            false);

    mSavedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
    round_Image = null;
    if (mSavedInstanceState == null) {
        taken_image = null;
        round_Image = null;
        upload_image_hd = null;
    }

    mViewUtils = new ViewUtils(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    boolean checker=getActivity().getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
    System.out.println("bbool"+checker);
    if(checker)
        Reference.DEVICEHEIGHT=600;
    else
        Reference.DEVICEHEIGHT=400;
    // dummy call//
    allSportsFromServer();
    // updateCustomerSportsToServer();

    mMessage = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab2_wrapper);
    mfollow = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab1_wrapper);
    mNotify = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab3_wrapper);
    mPhoto = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab4_wrapper);
    // mMenuIcon = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.one_wrapper);
    // mMenuSave = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.two_wrapper);
    // mMenuSaveButton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_image_save);
    mUsername = mViewUtils.createTextView(view.findViewById(R.id.Username),
            false);
    tag = mViewUtils.createTextView(view.findViewById(R.id.usertag), false);
    mAge = mViewUtils.createTextView(view.findViewById(R.id.age), false);
    mPlace = mViewUtils
            .createTextView(view.findViewById(R.id.place), false);
    mLikeCount = mViewUtils.createTextView(
            view.findViewById(R.id.like_count), false);
    mFolloCount = mViewUtils.createTextView(
            view.findViewById(R.id.follw_count), false);
    mProgressBar = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_image);
    dummyimage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cover_image_dummy);
    mViewUtils.createTextView(view.findViewById(R.id.photo_text), false);
    mViewUtils.createTextView(view.findViewById(R.id.follw_text), false);

    mUserProfile = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cover_image);

    System.out.println("new user" + Reference.newuser);
    if (!Reference.newuser) {
        dummyimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mUserProfile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    mEdit = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.edit);
    mGender = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.gender);
    grid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridviewsports);
    mlike = mViewUtils.createIconTextView(view.findViewById(R.id.like));
    mMessage_icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_msg);
    mNotify_icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_notify);

    mMsgCount = mViewUtils.createTextView(
            view.findViewById(R.id.msg_count), false);
    mNotifyCount = mViewUtils.createTextView(
            view.findViewById(R.id.notify_count), false);

    mPhoto_icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_photo);

    // mListview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_all);
    // mRecive = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_my);
    firstload = true;
    grid.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(getActivity()));
    // Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
    // R.anim.grid_animation);
    // grid.setAnimation(anim);
    // anim.start();

    mNotify_icon.setTag(R.string.type, "notifyicon");
    mMessage_icon.setTag(R.string.type, "messageicon");
    mPhoto_icon.setTag(R.string.type, "photoicon");

    mMessage.setTag(R.string.type, "messageicon");
    mNotify.setTag(R.string.type, "notifyicon");
    mPhoto.setTag(R.string.type, "photoicon");
    // mMenuSaveButton.setTag(R.string.type, "sportsSave");
    mfollow.setTag(R.string.type, "followicon");

    mMessage.setOnClickListener(this);
    mNotify.setOnClickListener(this);
    mPhoto.setOnClickListener(this);
    mfollow.setOnClickListener(this);
    mMessage_icon.setOnClickListener(this);
    mNotify_icon.setOnClickListener(this);
    mPhoto_icon.setOnClickListener(this);
    // mMenuSaveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    System.out.println("step 336");
    return view;
}

public static Context getinstance() {

    return context;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    System.out.println("step 348");
    try {
        if (round_Image != null) {

            mUserProfile.setImageBitmap(round_Image);

        }

        String User_Name = PreferencesUtils.getData(
                Reference.USER_FIRSTNAME, getActivity()
                        .getApplicationContext());
        String User_Age = PreferencesUtils.getData(Reference.USER_AGE,
                getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        String User_Country = PreferencesUtils.getData(
                Reference.USER_LOCATION, getActivity()
                        .getApplicationContext());
        String User_Gender = PreferencesUtils.getData(
                Reference.USER_GENDER_G, getActivity()
                        .getApplicationContext());
        String User_Follow = PreferencesUtils.getData(
                Reference.SERVER_USER_FOLLOWER_COUNT, getActivity()
                        .getApplicationContext());
        String User_Profile = PreferencesUtils.getData(
                Reference.SERVER_USER_CROPPED_PHOTO_URL, getActivity()
                        .getApplicationContext());
        String User_Message_Count = PreferencesUtils.getData(
                Reference.SERVER_USER_MESSAGE_COUNT, getActivity()
                        .getApplicationContext());
        String User_Notification_Count = PreferencesUtils.getData(
                Reference.SERVER_USER_NOTIFICATION_COUNT, getActivity()
                        .getApplicationContext());
        String User_Like_Count = PreferencesUtils.getData(
                Reference.SERVER_USER_LIKE_COUNT, getActivity()
                        .getApplicationContext());
        String User_Sports = PreferencesUtils.getData(
                Reference.SERVER_USER_SELECT_SPORTS, getActivity()
                        .getApplicationContext());
        String All_Sports = PreferencesUtils.getData(
                Reference.SERVER_ALL_SPORTS, getActivity()
                        .getApplicationContext());

        String tagline = PreferencesUtils.getData(Reference.TAGuser,
                getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        if (!User_Name.equals("") && !User_Age.equals("")
                && !User_Age.equals("") && !User_Country.equals("")
                && !User_Gender.equals("") && !User_Follow.equals("")
                && !User_Message_Count.equals("")
                && !User_Notification_Count.equals("")
                && !User_Like_Count.equals("") && !All_Sports.equals("")
                && !User_Sports.equals("") && !tagline.equals("")) {

            String[] strArr = User_Name.split(" ");
            StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();
            for (String str : strArr) {
                char[] stringArray = str.trim().toCharArray();
                stringArray[0] = Character.toUpperCase(stringArray[0]);
                str = new String(stringArray);

                res.append(str).append(" ");
                mUsername.setText((res.toString().trim()));
            }

            if (tagline.trim().length() > 0)
                tag.setText(tagline);
            else
                tag.setText(R.string.DEFAULT_TAG);
            mAge.setText(User_Age);
            mPlace.setText(User_Country);
            mFolloCount.setText(User_Follow);
            if (User_Gender.equals("male")) {
                mAge.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
                        R.color.blue_light));
                mGender.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.ic_me_male));
            } else {
                mAge.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.pink));
                mGender.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.ic_switch_female));
            }
            // PROFILE PICTURE

            System.out.println("user picc" + User_Profile);
            if (User_Profile.equalsIgnoreCase("0")
                    || User_Profile.trim().length() == 0) {
                // mUserProfile.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.noimagesmall));
                dummyimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mUserProfile.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                try {

                    String imageURL = User_Profile;
                    // Log.d("ENTERED_IN_THE_IMAGE_URL", "" + imageURL);
                    System.out.println("setting cropped line 413"
                            + imageURL);
                    mImageLoader.displayImage(imageURL, mUserProfile,
                            mOptions);
                    mUserProfile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // mUserProfile.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.noimagesmall));
                    dummyimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mUserProfile.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            // DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            // getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
            // final int windowheight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
            // final int windowwidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
            //
            // mUserProfile.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            //
            // @Override
            // public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
            // mUserProfile.getLayoutParams();
            // switch(event.getAction())
            // {
            // case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // break;
            // case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // int x_cord = (int)event.getRawX();
            // int y_cord = (int)event.getRawY();
            //
            // if(x_cord>windowwidth){x_cord=windowwidth;}
            // if(y_cord>windowheight){y_cord=windowheight;}
            //
            // layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord -55;
            // layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord - 75;
            //
            // mUserProfile.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            // break;
            // default:
            // break;
            // }
            // return true;
            // }
            // });
            // MESSAGE COUNT

            if (User_Message_Count.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                mMsgCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                mMsgCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mMsgCount.setText(User_Message_Count);
            }

            // NOTIFICATION COUNT

            if (User_Notification_Count.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                mNotifyCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                mNotifyCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mNotifyCount.setText(User_Notification_Count);
            }

            // LIKE COUNT
            if (User_Like_Count.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                mLikeCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                mLikeCount.setText(User_Like_Count);
            }

            // ALL SPORTS

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(All_Sports);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String SportsName = obj
                            .getString(Reference.SPORTS_NAME);

                    // mListview_all.add(SportsName);

                }
                // mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // USER SELECTED SPORTS
            if (mSportDb.sportsExists()) {

                mSportDb.emptyAuth();
            }

            try {

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(User_Sports);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    int SportsId = Integer.parseInt(obj
                            .getString(Reference.SPORTS_ID_RE));
                    String SportsName = obj
                            .getString(Reference.SPORTS_NAME);
                    mSportDb.createAuth(SportsId, SportsName, "1");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            getProfileDetailServer();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("exxxceptionn");
    }
    if(Constants.DIALOGOPEN){
        Constants.DIALOGOPEN=false;
        Constants.dialog.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    System.out.println("step 574");
    mEdit.setTag(R.string.type, "edit");
    mEdit.setOnClickListener(this);

    taken_image = null;
    round_Image = null;
    upload_image_hd = null;

    // String listCount = String.valueOf(mListview_all.size());

    // mListview_all.clear();
    // mListview_new.clear();
    // mListview_my.clear();

    initializeUIElements(); // ADD TO SPORTS FUNCTION
    // setupDragDropStuff();
    // setupDropStuff();
    //
    getProfileDetailServer();

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    System.out.println("step 599");

    try {

        if (((PreferencesUtils.getData(Reference.USER_ID, getActivity()))
                .length() > 0)
                && (PreferencesUtils.getData(Reference.USER_ID,
                        getActivity()) != null)) {

            getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,
                    new IntentFilter(Reference.REFREASH_PROFILE));
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 3);

            profileServiceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                    ProfileService.class);
            pIntent = PendingIntent
                    .getService(getActivity(), 0, profileServiceIntent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            alarm = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
                    Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cal.getTimeInMillis(), 7000, pIntent);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e);
    }

    // mListview_all.clear();
    // mListview_new.clear();
    // mListview_my.clear();

    Log.e("", "---> onResume");
    initializeUIElements(); // ADD TO SPORTS FUNCTION

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    try{
    alarm.cancel(pIntent);
    getActivity().stopService(profileServiceIntent);
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try{
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        alarm.cancel(pIntent);
        getActivity().stopService(profileServiceIntent);
        }
        catch(Exception e){

            System.out.println(e);
        }
    super.onDestroy();
}
@Override
public void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        alarm.cancel(pIntent);
        getActivity().stopService(profileServiceIntent);
        }
        catch(Exception e){

            System.out.println(e);
        }
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    String type = v.getTag(R.string.type).toString().trim();
    try {



        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")) {

            mEdit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            onClickEdit();
        }

        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("messageicon")) {
            ((FeedActivity) mHomeActivity).navigateToMessagePage();

        }
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("notifyicon")) {
            ((FeedActivity) mHomeActivity).navigateToNotificationPage();

        }
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("photoicon")) {
            ((FeedActivity) mHomeActivity).navigateToPhotoPage();

        }
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("sportsSave")) {

            createUserSportsServer();

        }
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("followicon")) {
            if (!mFolloCount.getText().toString().equals("0"))
                ((FeedActivity) mHomeActivity).navigateToFollowersPage(
                        "following", true);
        }

    } catch (NullPointerException ignored) {
    }
    catch (Exception e) {



    }

}
```

}

my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
 <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_headerr"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/markerboxcolor"
    android:layout_gravity="top"

    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

my error log is as follows

```
    06-08 12:09:08.667: E/AndroidRuntime(17491): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-08 12:09:08.667: E/AndroidRuntime(17491): Process: com.sports.sportspartners, PID: 17491
06-08 12:09:08.667: E/AndroidRuntime(17491): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-08 12:09:08.667: E/AndroidRuntime(17491):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:708)
06-08 12:09:08.667: E/AndroidRuntime(17491):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
06-08 12:09:08.667: E/AndroidRuntime(17491):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
06-08 12:09:08.667: E/AndroidRuntime(17491):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
06-08 12:09:08.667: E/AndroidRuntime(17491):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
06-08 12:09:08.667: E/AndroidRuntime(17491):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
06-08 12:09:08.667: E/AndroidRuntime(17491):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:249)
06-08 12:09:08.667: E/AndroidRuntime(17491):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
06-08 12:09:08.667: E/AndroidRuntime(17491):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
06-08 12:09:08.667: E/AndroidRuntime(17491):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:559)
06-08 12:09:08.667: E/AndroidRuntime(17491):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
06-08 12:09:08.667: E/AndroidRuntime(17491):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
06-08 12:09:08.667: E/AndroidRuntime(17491):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
06-08 12:09:08.667: E/AndroidRuntime(17491):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
06-08 12:09:08.667: E/AndroidRuntime(17491):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
06-08 12:09:08.667: E/AndroidRuntime(17491):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-08 12:09:08.667: E/AndroidRuntime(17491):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-08 12:09:08.667: E/AndroidRuntime(17491):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
06-08 12:09:08.667: E/AndroidRuntime(17491):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
06-08 12:09:08.667: E/AndroidRuntime(17491):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a **specific problem or error** and the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.*

Comment: here in stack overflow reviewers are competing to deduct marks by down voting rather than helping.Really fed up of this

Comment: paste log as text not a screen

Comment: @selvin please give me some guidelines for the same so that I can follow that.On getting a critical issue obviously  question guidelines will not run to mind.

Comment: take a look at [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702484/null-pointer-exception-on-view-pager-swipe#h-related) part of this site ... also, before asking it is nice to google for a part of the stacktrace to check if someone has similar question ...

Comment: @Selvin is it ok now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79920/discussion-between-karthika-pb-and-selvin).

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved the issue by adding `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);`

Comment: A good solution, definitely much easier than trying to cancel on going tasks or anything like that! Thanks